# как проверить существование программы на ПК?

Tags: windowsinstaller, autoit

Пишу скрипт на AutoIt Scripting чтобы автоматический установить программы без участия пользователя. Надо проверить есть ли эта программа или нет, если нет то установить, если да перейти на след. шаг.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит вообще-то от программы. Вариантов масса.

- Проверить наличие каталога по умолчанию, в который устанавливается программа, на существование. То же - для исполняемых модулей программы. То же - для каталогов и файлов в общих местоположениях (Application Data и т.п.). То же - для файлов, копируемых в системные каталоги (System32 и т.п.). Проверить наличие папки/ярлыков программы в главном меню.
- Проверить наличие в реестре сведений об установленной программе, при наличии там пути к каталогу установки - проверить его наличие и наличие там исполняемых модулей.
- Проверить в реестре наличие информации в секции Uninstall для этой программы.
- Если программа устанавливает свои обработчики и/или сервисы - проверить их наличие/доступность.
- Если программа формирует свои ассоциации, регистрирует свои типы и пр. - проверить их наличие.
- Если программа регистрирует повторно используемые библиотеки- проверить в реестре их регистрацию.

И т.д., и т.п.

Comment: а можно как то попроще ?

Comment: Да даже это всё вместе при всех положительных ответах не даст стопроцентной гарантии, что софт установлен правильно и работоспособен...

Comment: а как сделать так: например мы запускаем install и там он выводит кнопки изменить, удалить если это прога уже есть. как проверить значение кнопки ?

Comment: Сделать скриншот, прогнать через OCR... не знаю, короче.